# What's the real nature of Samantha Black Crow in American Gods?

Tags: american-gods

Sam is shown in the end as having dreams similar to Shadow. What is the author hinting at?

(Edit: Its not a duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159932) question as some people have suggested, because that question deals with Shadow's dreams, while my question deals with Sam's dreams and the possible implications for that)

Comment: Similar question from another site: [What was the purpose of Sam Black Crow in American Gods?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3080/17)

Comment: That answer doesn't properly address *why* Sam was having those dreams, and what does it tell us about her character

Comment: Sure. I didn't say it *answers* your question, just that it's *related*. It might be interesting for you or for people viewing your question.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did everyone find out about Shadow's dream?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159932/how-did-everyone-find-out-about-shadows-dream)

Answer (score 2):

We don't know. My personal theory is that she is a demigod like Shadow, but Neil never confirmed nor denied it. Her father acts somewhat like Odin, wandering every few years. Marrying a woman, living with her, getting wanderlust, moving, meeting and marrying another woman. Only he is Native American. He dismissively calls her halfbreed.

As for why she was having those dreams, if you read the relevant chapter things become slightly clearer. Right after Shadow wakes up from lightning bird dream, he gets a call from Wednesday and gets scolded by him, to the tune of "What is the point of hiding you in the middle of nowhere if you're going to do that and shine like a beacon?" . I think that everybody around the Shadow or connected with him shared the dream of lightning birds at the time he had his dream. In fact, I think there is a couple of sentences which implies that people complained of odd dreams the next morning.